# How to fix the enterprise manager configuration failed?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

[image]

Enterprise manager configuration failed due to the following error-

> Error updating
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/sysman/emd/targets.xml

Comment: Hi, what is in the log file that the error message refers to? If you haven't looked in there, it may resolve your problem anyway.

Comment: and did you try manually running /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/emca script?

Answer (score 0):

```
emca -deconfig dbcontrol db -repos drop
```

then as sysdba

```
drop user sysman cascade;
drop public synonym system;
drop role mgmt_user;
drop public synonym mgmt_target_blackouts;
drop user mgmt_view;
```

Then

```
  emca -config dbcontrol db -repos create
```